# Show part of image in a circular arc

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibezierpath

I have an image which is like a progress bar in circle. I need to show only a part of the progress bar based on the progress percentage. What I am trying to do is to put the image inside an imageview and show only a part of the image (arc section of the entire circle) based  on the progress.

I have tried using UIBezierpath to create an arc shaped view and setting my progress bar image as the background image. But the image will try to fit inside the arc shaped view and looks bad.

Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Edit: Here is a sample image of what I am trying to achieve

[image: But instead of the blue background, I need an image]

But instead of the blue background, I need an image. So, only part of the image will be visible depending on the progress. (When its 100%, the entire image is visible)

I have spend almost half a day on this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Open Photoshop / Pixelmator / your favorite image editor to provide a mock up of what you want. We don't know what effect you are trying to achieve here

Comment: @Code Different: I am able to build as arc as above with uibezierpath.. but am not able to show an image in the background. (Tried using color with pattern image)